# Consumer to trigger api based on the messages sent by producer

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I made a consumer and producer class using spring. Now I want the consumer to trigger some api based on the messages sent by producer. How to do that?
Please provide solution in JAVA SpringBoot.
How to trigger an api from application.yml in consumer?

```java
@Service
public class KafkaConsumer{
   
    @KafkaListener(topics="mytopic", groupID="mygroup")
    public void receive(String message, Acknowledgement acknowledgement)){
           System.out.println("Consumer message "+ message);
    }
    // when I add @postMapping here then it gives error. 
    // How can I send a post request on the basis of message recieved?
}
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Regarding your question - _based on messages sent by producer_ - This is **the definition** of a Kafka Consumer. Stackoverflow is not for finding off-site tutorials, and any you find elsewhere should solve your problem, starting with the official Spring-Kafka / Spring-Integration-Kafka / Spring-Cloud-Streams documentation, so what _exact_ issues are you having?

Comment: I have made kafka producer and consumer properly and the messages are being sent and received properly. But, I want to trigger API in my consumer according to the messages received by it. So how to do that? I have searched numerous tutorials but couldn't find anything @OneCricketeer

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "trigger API". You can call whatever method you want if you are able to receive messages... Would you be able to [edit] your question to include your current code as a [mcve]?

Comment: Please check the question now. And please help. I am stuck at it for hours. @OneCricketeer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I add @postMapping here then it gives error

You can only add that annotation on REST server methods that handle *incoming requests*.

You are trying to make an *outgoing* HTTP call, then you need to use an HTTP Client of your choice, or a Spring `RestTemplate`

If you are trying to call any *internal HTTP endpoint*, then you should refactor your code to call methods of the same classes those HTTP resources interact with.

Comment: Thanks a lot I ll study Rest Template and add it. Just one little thing, how will that Rest Template help me in getting items from application.yml?

Comment: It doesn't. Data in your YAML properties is not available from HTTP. At least, not by default.

Comment: Oh ok. Then how am I supposed to return string based on that application.yml ?

Comment: You'd use `@Value` annotations to bind fields to configuration values. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config Or you can bind `@Autowired private Environment env;` field then, use `env.getProperty` to find any property from the file.